# passed object nil into my second view

Tags: iphone, object, uiviewcontroller, ios5

I have a CalendarView and I've passed the object to another UIView with a tableView in it.

In my CalendarView:

```
    anotherView *anotherViewController = [[anotherView alloc] init];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:aDateObject];
    anotherViewController.eventDate = aDateObject;
    anotherViewController.eventDateTitle = dateString;

    [formatter release];
    [anotherViewController release];
```

I don't know why my object its nil in anotherView...

Comment: Is the dateformatter setup correctly, add some debug lines.

Comment: @rckoenes: I think I'm doing the right way...

Comment: Check the date out putted by the dateformatter, Whats in the date string? if it is any other format then `26-11-2001` it will not work.

Comment: @rckoenes: the date out putted by the dateformatter is dd-mm-yyyy; as you specified... I think it should be anything else...

Comment: That's not what I meant, what the value of `dateString`.

Comment: @rckoenes: the value of `dateString` is `15-11-2011`

Comment: Then we know that the date object is correct and the output is there. Have set the the properties of the other viewcontroller to retain? also where do you present the instance of anotherViewController?

Comment: @rckoenes: Yes, the `retain` properties are being set to `retain`. I'm instantiate `anotherViewController` by including the files and simply `anotherView *anotherViewController = [[anotherView alloc] init];`

Comment: Yes I see that, but where do you present it, I only see that you release it.

Comment: @rckoenes: I'm not sure I'm doing that... can give me an example?

Comment: You your are not use the instance of `anotherViewController` only this instance has the variables you set. you must display it like:`[self presentModalViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];` or use the navigation controller. If `anotherViewController` is a view that already exist this will not fill that instance properties, you will need that instance and not create a new instance.

Comment: @rckoenes: oh, now I figure it oud what you've meant; I'm doing this way: `[self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5394/discussion-between-el-severo-and-rckoenes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As el.severo says in the comments, ensure you log every step.  Also there are issues with [locales](http://lukeredpath.co.uk/blog/parsing-strings-with-nsdateformatter-gotcha.html), you need to set the correct locale GB and us regios have different interpretations of dates.  E.g. for US:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:locale];
[locale release];

NSLog(@"date obj:%@", aDateObject); 
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:aDateObject];
NSLog(@"date str:%@", dateString); 

anotherViewController.eventDate = aDateObject;
anotherViewController.eventDateTitle = dateString;
```